# How to remove Junk characters coming in gmail attachments in php?

Tags: php, gmail-imap

I have marked the junk characters in the image and I want the code to remove it and start reading the data after it.

[image]

Comment: What format is the data in?

Comment: What's the attached file?

Comment: @NijrajGelani OP want to read doc file in php and want to remove junk code.

Comment: why do you want to remove it? do you not care about attached files?

Comment: we are reading *.doc file from gmail attachment and that time we are getting this junk characters

Comment: @Sadikhasan well, someone's gotta tell him that he can't...

Comment: @NijrajGelani Any other option to read doc file with ignore junk code.

Comment: @Clayton : Our actual task is to read the resume attached with the mail and want to store it in database. We don't want to store file. So we want to remove junk characters.

Comment: The file is a word document.  You need to convert it to a plain text file or something readable.  simply 'removing the junk characters' is not the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That ugly looking text is not junk but something that makes a `*.doc` file a DOC file that it is (i.e. formatting). You can't really just echo that file using PHP.

You can display it using a some PHP doc viewer library though or if you can find some API online to convert DOC to TXT.

You can also make the user download it. Use `file_put_content()` to store that attachment into a doc file like below :

```
if(file_put_content("attachment.doc", $email['attachment'])){
    header("Location: attachment.doc");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your support

Comment: @swap Which OS are you using?

Comment: we are using Windows.

Answer (score 0):

The binary data represents a *.doc file. If you really want to extract plain text from it, you could do some fuzzy logic, and extract the lines that do not contain any characters with low ASCII codes (except for CR and LF).

Assuming your data structure is in *$data*, you could do this:

```
foreach($data as $element) {
    $element["attachment"] = preg_replace(
        "/^.*?[\x01-\x09,\x0B,\x0C,\x0E-\x1F].*?$\R?/m",
        "", $element["attachment"]);
}
```

Again, this is just "fuzzy" logic, so you still might get some meaningless text that is not removed.